# Compare arrays with strings (match parts of strings)

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, adobe-indesign, extendscript

I'm working on an InDesign script and need to compare two arrays with strings returning a new array with A + B elements that doesn't match A elements.

For example:

```
var a = ['LFC_Luis Felipe Corullon', 'FTP', 'WWW'];
var b = ['SEMA', 'LFC', 'HTTP', 'AVC'];
```

I need as result this:

```
['LFC_Luis Felipe Corullon', 'FTP', 'WWW', 'SEMA', 'HTTP', 'AVC']
```

Excluding 'LFC' because it matches with 'LFC_Luis Felipe Corullon'.

I tried this, but it loops forever...

```
var a = ["LFC_Luis Felipe Corullón" , "FTP" , "FMTP"];
var b = ["LFC" , "FDOT" , "SAS" , "ADA" , "SAE"];
//========================================================================================
alert(merge(a,b));

function merge(a,b) {
    var r = a;
    for (var i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
        var v = [];
        for (var j=0; j<b.length; j++) {
            if ( a[i].split("_")[0] == b[j] ) v.push(true);
            else v.push(false);
            }
        for (k in v) {
            if (v[k]==false) r.push(b[k]);
            }
        }
    return r;
    }
```

Any help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Copy `a` to the result. Then loop through `b`, testing if the element is a substring of any of `a`. If not, add it to the result. You can use `Array.prototype.some()` and `String.prototype.includes()` to perform that test.

Comment: I tried to search and just created my post because I can't find a solution. Thanks for answering.

Comment: So you expect us to do it for you because you can't figure it out yourself?

Comment: No. I expect help to understand how to do this. I'm not an expert and I think a community purpose is to help each other.

Comment: I tried to do that with my comment above. It's hard to go further without actually writing the whole code.

Comment: Programming is all about putting together a solution using building blocks like that. I understand you may not know what the right blocks are. But once you get that, you should be able to figure out how to combine them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm used to do it this way:

```js
var a = ['LFC_Luis Felipe Corullon', 'FTP', 'WWW'];
var b = ['SEMA', 'LFC', 'HTTP', 'AVC'];

var a_str = a.join('\t'); // convert the array into a string

for (var i in b) if (a_str.indexOf(b[i])<0) a.push(b[i]);

console.log(a); // or alert(a);
```

It can be even an one-liner if you don't care the performance:

```js
var a = ['LFC_Luis Felipe Corullon', 'FTP', 'WWW'];
var b = ['SEMA', 'LFC', 'HTTP', 'AVC'];

for (var i in b) if (a.join('\t').indexOf(b[i])<0) a.push(b[i]);

console.log(a);
```

The second solution, by the way, eliminates duplicated values from the result array:

```
var a = ['LFC_Luis Felipe Corullon', 'FTP', 'WWW'];
var b = ['LFC', 'AVC', 'AVC', 'AVC']; // <-- duplicates
```

result:

```
[ 'LFC_Luis Felipe Corullon', 'FTP', 'WWW', 'AVC' ] // <-- no duplicates
```

If you want to use RegExp to find matches it can be done this way:

```js
var a = ['LFC_Luis Felipe Corullon', 'FTP', 'WWW'];
var b = ['SEMA', 'LFC', 'ftp', 'HTTP', 'AVC'];

var a_str = a.join('\t'); // convert the array into a string

for (var i in b) {
    var reg = new RegExp(b[i], 'i'); // 'i' to ingore case for example
    if (!a_str.match(reg)) a.push(b[i]);
}

console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve this result using the [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes).

```js
var a = ["LFC_Luis Felipe Corullon", "FTP", "WWW"];
var b = ["SEMA", "LFC", "HTTP", "AVC"];

const result = [
  ...a,
  ...b.filter((str) => !a.some((s) => s.includes(str)))
];

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need. Thanks. But this works in the browser, not in ESTK and InDesign. Nice to see it's possible. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this code helping you

```
var a = ['LFC_Luis Felipe Corullon', 'FTP', 'WWW'];

var b = ['SEMA', 'LFC', 'HTTP', 'AVC'];
var result = [...a,...b.filter(o=>!a.some(v=>v.startsWith(o)))]
console.log(result)
```

Comment: you can't use `startsWith` here. Because OP wants to check if the text contains in other text. your code only works if it comes in starting only.

Comment: And Extendscript has no `filter()`, `some()`, `startWith()` functions and there is no `=>` notation and no spreads `[...array]`. :(

Answer (score 0):

Found a way. Thank you all.

```
var a = ["LFC_Luis Felipe Corullón" , "FTP" , "FMTP"];
var b = ["LFC" , "FDOT" , "SAS" , "ADA" , "SAE"];
//========================================================================================
alert(merge(a,b));

function merge(a,b) {
    var r = a;
    var v = b;
    for (var i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
        for (var j=0; j<b.length; j++) {
            if ( a[i].split("_")[0] == b[j] ) v.splice(j,1);
            }
        }
    r = r.concat(v);
    return r;
    }
```